# How to store the image ID in wordpress database (localhost)

Tags: php, wordpress

HI first of thanks and i love this community . I stuck in problem where i want to store the image/item ID in localhost wordpress database instead of image path. I tried everything but failed. Well i am newbie in wordpress so i need a help.

suppose my image/item id is like:---- http://localhost/wpmegameta/wp-admin/upload.php?item=45

databse path:----http://localhost/wpmegameta/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/coding.png

and i want to store only 45 in database

Wordpress database Screenshot
[image]

and I want to store only 45 in database like this ---
[image]

```
    wp_nonce_field( 'case_study_bg_submit', 'case_study_bg_nonce' );
    $lacuna2_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="case-study-bg" class="lacuna2-row-title">Practice Area Icon Image</label>
    <img style="max-width:200px;height:auto;" id="meta-image-preview" src="<?php if ( isset ( $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ){ echo $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'][0]; } ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="meta-image" id="meta-image" class="meta_image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ){ echo $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'][0]; } ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="Choose or Upload an Image" />
    </p>
<script>
jQuery('#meta-image-button').click(function() {

    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {

        jQuery('#meta-image').val(attachment.url);
    jQuery('#meta-image-preview').attr('src',attachment.url);
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
    }

    wp.media.editor.open();

    return false;
});
</script>
<?php    

}

/**
 * Add Case Study background image metabox to the back end of Case Study posts
 */

function lacuna2_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'case-study-bg', 'Game Image', 'lacuna2_case_study_bg', 'post', 'side', 'low' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'lacuna2_add_meta_boxes' );

/**
 * Save background image metabox for Case Study posts
 */

function save_case_study_bg_meta_box($post_id ) {
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'case_study_bg_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'case_study_bg_nonce' ], 'case_study_bg_submit' ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce  ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] ) ) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-image', $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_case_study_bg_meta_box' );
```

In wordpress

```
Image /Item ID==45

Image Path== http://localhost/wpmegameta/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/coding.png
```

i want to store the image/item ID in wordpress database like=45

Answer (score 0):

i think it's stander to store the image URL ,
but if you want to store just the id do that is to create a table contain all images URL's
and contains tow columns : ID,URL
hope this useful .